# UPS in front of an ATS for generator protection

Tags: generator, load, ups, power-grid, ats

At the countryside house there is this setup:
[image]

And I am trying to protect the generator and house load from brief ~ 1s power outages like so:

[image]

It works fine in normal conditions. Trouble is when I turn off the UPS output as to simulate an outage the ATS won't start the generator. I have just thought that maybe by turning off the UPS output then Live and Neutral are left floating and that could somehow impact ATS outage detection?

Comment: Put the UPS between ATS and house maybe?

Comment: Are you planning to support fridge, freezer and cooker with the ups?

Comment: @Andyaka I have seen that setup on the interwebs, but will it prevent the generator from starting up during a brief outage?

Comment: @SolarMike yes sir, multiple fridges and freezers.